# Spark serialization error mystery

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, jvm

Let's say i have the following code:

```
class Context {
  def compute() = Array(1.0)
}
val ctx = new Context
val data = ctx.compute
```

Now we are running this code in Spark:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))
rdd.map(_ + data(0)).count()
```

The code above throws `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. I'm **not asking how to fix it**, by extending Serializable or making a case class, i want to understand why the error happens.

The thing that i don't understand is why it complains about Context class not being a `Serializable`, though it's not a part of the lambda: `rdd.map(_ + data(0))`. `data` here is an Array of values which should be serialized, but it seems that JVM also captures `ctx` reference as well, which, in my understanding, should not happening.

As i understand, in the shell Spark should clear lambda from the repl context. If we print the tree after `delambdafy` phase, we would see these pieces:

```
object iw extends Object {
  ... 
  private[this] val ctx: $line11.iw$Context = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def ctx(): $line11.iw$Context = iw.this.ctx;
  private[this] val data: Array[Double] = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def data(): Array[Double] = iw.this.data; 
  ...
}

class anonfun$1 ... {
  final def apply(x$1: Int): Double = anonfun$1.this.apply$mcDI$sp(x$1);
  <specialized> def apply$mcDI$sp(x$1: Int): Double = x$1.+(iw.this.data().apply(0));
  ...
}
```

So the decompiled lambda code that is sent to the worker node is: `x$1.+(iw.this.data().apply(0))`. Part `iw.this` belongs to the Spark-Shell session, so, as i understand, it should be cleared by the [ClosureCleaner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala#L32), since has nothing to do with the logic and shouldn't be serialized. Anyway, calling `iw.this.data()` returns an `Array[Double]` value of the `data` variable, which is initialized in the constructor:

```
def <init>(): type = {
  iw.super.<init>();
  iw.this.ctx = new $line11.iw$Context();
  iw.this.data = iw.this.ctx().compute(); // <== here
  iw.this.res4 = ...
  ()
}
```

In my understanding `ctx` value has nothing to do with the lambda, it's not a closure, hence shouldn't be serialized. What am i missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: I{m not quite sure but I think your logic is sound. I would expect to have a parent class or closure some such that encapsulates both the definition of "Context" and the "data" variable. Spark might be trying to serialize such parent instance and complaining because the inner class is not serializeable (making all of it not serializeable), not as directly as you make it sound, but then you would need to see the entire code structure rather than short snippets.

Comment: @DanielL. Well, that's the question, since the failure happens on the driver side, i.e no actual serialization happens. If i understand correctly, before serializing Spark checks if the code if safe to be serialized and if not, throws an error. So the real question is why Spark considers this code not serializable.

Comment: Spark will need to serialize closures (code) to the executors. There is the possibility I mention up there, but you need to show the code that surrounds  `class Context` and `rdd.map`... paste more code...

Comment: @DanielL. The code i gave here suffices for the error, since it fails in repl as well. Actually i figured it out, you were right in your assumption. The code fails because `ctx` variable is not serializable and it seems that spark ClosureCleaner doesn't remove surronding `iw` object as i initially thought, hence we have the error. Though i don't understand why `iw` context is not cleared away by Spark. Anyway, thank you, if you can write a comprehensible answer i will accept it

Comment: Glad you fixed it, let me see if I can explain it comprehensively as you say.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818001/understanding-spark-serialization/40818002#40818002

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with what Spark considers it can use as a closure safely. This is in some cases very intuitive, since Spark uses reflection and in many cases can't recognize some of Scala's guarantees (not a full compiler or anything) or the fact that some variables in the same object are irrelevant. For safety, Spark will attempt to serialize any objects referenced, which in your case includes `iw`, which is not serializable.

The code inside [ClosureCleaner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala#L32) has a good example:

> For instance, transitive cleaning is necessary in the following
>   scenario:
>
> ```
> class SomethingNotSerializable {
>   def someValue = 1
>   def scope(name: String)(body: => Unit) = body
>   def someMethod(): Unit = scope("one") {
>     def x = someValue
>     def y = 2
>       scope("two") { println(y + 1) }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, scope "two" is not serializable because it references scope "one", which references SomethingNotSerializable. Note that, however, the body of scope "two" does not actually depend on SomethingNotSerializable. This means we can safely null out the parent pointer of a cloned scope "one" and set it the parent of scope "two", such that scope "two" no longer references SomethingNotSerializable transitively.

Probably the easiest fix is to create a local variable, in the same scope, that extracts the value from your object, such that there is no longer any reference to the encapsulating object inside the lambda:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3))
val data0 = data(0)
rdd.map(_ + data0).count()
```